# can I open/show folder "Download" in my app in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want open or show a folder in my app from my phone
when user press a button "open folder" show folder download

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find npm package for this.

the best thing of react native is you can find npm package for almost everything
check out this

[expo-file-system-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-file-system-view)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I can not use from expo, just show folder download no open file ant etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-native-fs packgae.you can with this package show downlod address.

Comment: just show me folder download no open file or etc.